# Correct interpretation of Lmer output

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have produced the following model:

```
>lmer(TotalPayoff~PgvnD*Type+Type*Asym+PgvnD*Asym+Game*Type+Game*PgvnD+Game*Asym+
                   (1|Subject)+(1|Pairing),REML=FALSE,data=table1)->m1

PgvnD=A percentage (numeric)
Asym= a factor 0 or 1
Type=a factor 1 or 2
Game= a factor 1 or 2
```

from this model the terms `Type`, `Game` and `PgvnD:Asym` were shown to be  significant by removal from the model. `PgvnD` and `Asym` on there own were not significant but were left in the model because the interaction between them was. The summary of this model is as follows;

```
> m7
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
Formula: TotalPayoff ~ Type + PgvnD * Asym + Game + (1 | Subject) + (1 |Pairing) 
   Data: table1 
  AIC  BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 1014 1038 -497.8    995.6   964.4
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept)   0.000   0.0000 
 Pairing  (Intercept) 716.101  26.7601 
 Residual              89.364   9.4533 
Number of obs: 113, groups: Subject, 73; Pairing, 61

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   81.727      6.332  12.907
Type2          7.926      2.852   2.779
PgvnD         -8.466      7.554  -1.121
Asym1        -12.167      7.583  -1.604
Game2         15.374      7.147   2.151
PgvnD:Asym1   26.618      9.710   2.741

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Type2  PgvnD  Asym1  Game2 
Type2       -0.188                            
PgvnD       -0.218 -0.038                     
Asym1       -0.620  0.081  0.189              
Game2       -0.483  0.009 -0.010 -0.015       
PgvnD:Asym1  0.233 -0.267 -0.766 -0.328 -0.011
```

Am I interpreting these results correctly?

- `TotalPayoff` is higher when `Type=1` than in `Type=2`, it is also higher when `game=2` than when `game=1`.
- Also `TotalPayoff` increases significantly with `PgvnD` if `Asym=1` but not if `ASym=0` (indicated by significant interaction term but non-significant single terms).

Also I notice that the `Subject` random effect has SD and variance of 0. Can this then be removed from the model? What does this really mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I address your interpretations 1 and 2 in order:

1) How you interpret factors depends on which level of the factor is the reference category. The fact that the model calls it `Type2` suggests to me that `Type1` is the reference, and that the parameter represents how the estimate changes when `Type == 2`. Thus, I disagree with your interpretation. I would say `TotalPayoff` is higher when `Type == 2` because the parameter is positive and significant (assuming alpha == .05).

2) I think your interpretation basically makes sense. I prefer to say it like this: The slope for `PgvnD` changes by the amount estimated as the parameter for the interaction term when `Asym == 1` (i.e. when Asym is not equal to the reference category). So the `PgvnD` parameter is its main effect estimate plus the interaction estimate when `Asym == 1`. This would be `-8.466 + 26.618`. Keep in mind, though, if you want to make an estimate of `TotalPayoff` you must also account for the main effect of `Asym`. Bottom line, the interaction parameter tells you how much the main effects change under the conditions specified by the interaction (value of `PgvnD` and the `Asym == 1`).

Alternatively, the interaction allows you to say that the effect of `Asym==1` on `TotalPayoff` changes positively along with changes in `PgvnD` by the amount estimated as the interaction parameter.

A quick example: ignoring all but the two discussed main effects which I now refer to as $A$ and $P$, and the interaction $AP$,

$$ y = \beta_{A}A + \beta_{P}P + \beta_{AP}AP $$

Clearly, if $A$ is $0$ (i.e. reference category), then neither the $AP$ interaction nor the main effect for $A$ contributes anything to $y$. But $\beta_PP$ still does so long as $P \ne 0$.

If $A = 1$ (i.e. probably meaning Asym is true, or not reference), and $P = 1$, then

$$y = \beta_{A}(1) + \beta_{P}(1) + \beta_{AP}(1 \times 1)$$

$$y = -12.167 + -8.466 + 26.618$$

Finally, I think it is probably safe to remove the variance component that was estimated 0 from the model. It might be worth it to explore the data a little to make sure that it seems like a reasonable estimate and not an artifact of a misspecified model or other oddity.

Comment: Hi 1)sorry yes that was my mistake Type==2 is higher than Type==1

Comment: Hi Thanks 1)sorry yes that was my mistake Type==2 is higher than Type==1.   2) You say the PgvnD parameter is -8.466 + 26.618=18.152. Does this mean that when Asym==0 the slope for PgvnD is 18.152? and so when Asym==0, TotalPayoff still increase with PgvnD just not as much as when Asym==1. Could you therefore say for Asym==0 the effect of PgvnD on TotalPayoff is positive but non-significant but with Asym==1 it is positive and significant?

Comment: It's worth commenting that using factors with levels called 0 and 1, and 1 and 2 adds considerable confusion to interpretation. I recommend giving the levels of the factors meaningful names to ease interpretation. Alternatively, use dummy variables in the standard way by naming a dummy sensibly (I assume you're not using dummies, but factors which are then converted to dummies in a R-special way).

Comment: I made an error in the last sentence of this comment but couldn't edit. Remade the comment instead.   
Re comment #2: The PgvnD slope moves to 18.152 when Asym==1 because the interaction was estimated 26.618 (26.618 - 8.466 == 18.152). When Asym==0 (the reference), then PgvnD parameter is just as it was estimated -8.466. This is because the contribution to TotalPayoff from the `Asym:PgvnD` parameter is effectively 0 when `Asym:PgvnD` is 0 (i.e. Beta * PgvnD * 0 = 0)